# update Anaconda packages in air-gapped environment

Tags: python-2.7, updates, redhat, anaconda

For regulatory reasons my company has deployed an air-gapped Red Hat environment with, among other, Python Anaconda and R installed. How to I go about updating Anaconda packages in such an environment? I can move files from my own machine to the environment via FTP but cannot access the internet directly from the air-gapped environment.
I usually update my anaconda packages with something like this:

```
conda update scipy
```

Comment: Take a look at http://continuum.io/anaconda-server

Answer (score 4):

The answers appears to be here in the Anaconda FAQ:

http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#install-pkgs-offline

How do I install packages into Anaconda offline?
You can directly install a conda package if you have it available on your local machine (use the full path for the package to ensure conda finds it):

conda install .tar.bz2
If you do not have the package on the target machine, you’ll need to move a copy of .tar.bz2 to it. Packages installed by conda are found in the anaconda/pkgs directory.

You can also install a tar-file directly (.tar) that itself contains many conda packages at any path location. You can make it easily using tar and then install it directly as well. No internet connection is needed as long as the tar-file is available on the target machine. Use the full path for the tar-file to ensure conda finds it:

conda install .tar

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I have the tar.bz2 in /home/user/miniconda3/pkgs/<package-name>.tar.bz2 and running `conda install /home/user/miniconda3/pkgs/<package-name>.tar.bz2` yields the same error when "fetching package metadata"

I have tried using the `--offline` and `--use-local` flags but the first has the same result and the second fails as the wrong version of conda.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work when the package you want recursively requires lots of dependencies? how would you get all of the dependencies into a tar file, without setting your hair on fire?